# Какой протокол передачи данных, использует stackoverflow.com

Tags: http, https, протоколы, stackoverflow-api

Какой протокол передачи данных, использует stackoverflow.com?
Интересует **протокол прикладного уровня**.

Интересно, когда находишься на странице, то её не обязательно обновлять для того что бы увидеть новые ответ или комментарий. Получается или веб-приложение stackoverflow.com запрашивает через каждые n секунд, работая через HTTP, или использует протокол двусторонней связи.

Comment: ajax и/или websocket

Comment: `wss://qa.sockets.stackexchange.com/` - вебсокеты

Answer (score 1):

[Из первых рук](http://nickcraver.com/blog/2016/02/17/stack-overflow-the-architecture-2016-edition/) ([перевод](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2669/%D0%90%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0-stack-overflow-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F-2016))

> Мы используем Websockets для осуществления принудительных обновлений в режиме реального времени, таких как показ уведомлений в верхнем горизонтальном меню, подсчет голосов, формирование статистики новой навигации, показ новых ответов и комментариев, и еще для нескольких задач.